# How can I search for an item in multiple table

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, e-commerce

Recently i am into E-commerce application, here i want to search the products according to category name or sub category name or product name.
 here i am planning to create table for Category, subcategory and products.
 If i search for an item, that can be category name or sub category name or product name, accordingly the products should be displayed.

Eg. Men-Shirt-Peterengland/Levis/john player/

If i search the text 'shirt' all the products(Peterengland/Levis/john player/) should be displayed. If i search perterengland ,only that product to be displayed. If i search with the main category all the subcategories and all products under this sub categories should be displayed.

Help me if any one have an idea on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in SQL with [Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms142571.aspx), you can query multiple tables with multiple words.

If you prefer your search logic to stay in C#, there are .NET search libraries, [Lucene.Net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/) is one of the most popular.